# Laravel 5.2 giving strange error on Azure

Tags: php, laravel, azure, encryption

I am trying to run a Laravel App on azure with PHP 5.6. 
But I am getting the following error:

```
FatalErrorException in Encrypter.php line 11:
Declaration of Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter::encrypt() must be compatible with Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\Encrypter::encrypt($value, $serialize = true)
```

Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the exception, I infer that the implementation of encrypt conflicts with the interface. Have you modified the `/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually it was laravel version conflict